# R unlist returns different results on a different environment

Tags: r

I have a script that queries for the max date in a table and stores that value in a character() string. In my original I was to do an as.Date(unlist(max_date)) but that doesn't work when I transfer the script to production.

Non_prod unlist = 2019-01-15
Prod unlist = 17911

At first I thought maybe it was the R version so I switched both environments to 3.5.2. Still no luck.

Comment: If you provide some sample of your table it'd be easier to help you out. Anyway, you can do `as.character(max_date)`!

Comment: as.character returns a value of "1". the table data is irrelevant. I have a max date that I need to convert from a string to a date and the unlist function is behaving differently in two different environments.

Comment: What are the two environments?

Comment: Windows VMs, both running R 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue I was having. The issue was that the odbc connection was pointing to a different driver in the DSN. I switched the drivers to match across both domains and now the unlist function works as expected.